# CSS Child selector is confusing me

Tags: css, css-selectors

CSS

```css
#nav > li {
  list-style:none;
  letter-spacing:3px;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About US</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Mobile Development</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Consultancy</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I am using child selector to make the list style none, which only unstyles children list items. But, letter-spacing property is adding spacing to the grandchildren list items. It is confusing me.

Comment: Some properties are inheritable. The child selector won't stop this inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of `letter-spacing`, `text-*` and `font-*` are to inherit from the parent. So you have reset on your children:

```css
#nav > li {
  list-style: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
#nav > li li {
  letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About US</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Consultancy</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you please suggest a good css book? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: @NeerajGupta I would suggest you to go through MDN. That's one of the best resources. And you have CSS Tricks. They are easy to find online. `:)`

Answer (score -1):

```
#nav > li {
  list-style:none;
  letter-spacing:3px;
  ul{
    list-style:none;
    letter-spacing:0;
  }
}
```

or

```
#nav > li {
  list-style:none;
  letter-spacing:3px;
  ul{
    li{
      list-style:none;
      letter-spacing:0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is totally invalid or useless! `:(` Does it even work?

Comment: in the question there is CSS... your answer should use CSS